# Math Vector Matrix multiplication

Tags: java, opengl

As far as I know the opengl Viewport's Coordinate System is 2Dimensional and ranges between -1 and 1 in x and y direction.To map a 3DVector's position from "World Space" to Viewport Coordinates you write f.e

"gl_position=uModelViewProjectionMatrix * vPosition " in your fragment shader.

My Question is how you can multiply a 3DVector by a 4D Matrix and get a 2DVector as a result and - more important - is there a funktion to do this on CPU side (especially a libary/ class for java in android)

Comment: You wouldn't assign to `gl_Position` in the fragment shader. This is a predefined variable in the **vertex** shader.

Answer (score 1):

Just clarifying a few terms:

- The viewport is the region within the window you're drawing to. It's specified in pixels.
- The rasterizer needs coordinates in *normalized device coordinates* which is -1 to 1. It then maps these to the viewport area.
- `gl_Position` must take a 4D vector in *clip space*. This is the space triangles are clipped in (for example and particularly if they intersect the near plane). This is separate to normalized device coordinates because the perspective divide hasn't happened yet. Doing this yourself would be `pos /= pos.w`, but that loses some information OpenGL needs for clipping, depth and interpolation.

This brings me to the answer. You're correct, you can't multiply a 3D vector by a 4x4 matrix. It's actually using **[homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics)** and the vector is 4D with a `1` at the end. The 4D result is for clip space. The rasterizer creates fragments with just the 2D position, but `w` is used for perspective correct interpolation and `z` is interpolated for depth testing.

Finally, the ModelViewProjection matrix implies the introduction of three more spaces. These are purely convention but with good reasons to exist. Mesh vertices are given in object space. You can place objects in the world with a *model* transformation matrix. You provide a camera position and rotation in the world with the view matrix. The projection matrix then defines the viewing volume by scaling everything for clip space. A reason to separate the view and projection matrices is for operations in eye space such as lighting calculations.

I won't go into any more detail, but hopefully this sets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know the opengl Viewport's Coordinate System is 2Dimensional and ranges between -1 and 1 in x and y direction.

Sort of, but not exactly like that.

From a mathematical point of view what matters is the dimension of the kernel. When it comes to the framebuffer things don't end at the viewport coordinates. From there things get "split", the (x,y) coordinate is used to determine which fragment to touch and the (z,w) coordinates usually are used for calculations that ultimately end in the depth buffer.

> My Question is how you can multiply a 3DVector by a 4D Matrix and get a 2DVector as a result

By padding the 3d vector to 4d elements; in terms of homogenous coordinates pad it with zeros except for the last element which is set to 1. This allows you to multiply with a n×4 matrix. And to get back to 2d you project it down into the lower dimension vector space; this is just like a 3d object projects a 2d shadow onto a surface. The simplemost projection is simply omitting the dimensions you're not interested in, like dropping z and w when going to the viewport.

> is there a function to do this on CPU side

There are several linear algebra libraries. Just pad the vectors accordingly to transform with higher dimension matrices and project them to get to lower dimensions.